# While Running LeanFT Scripts from ALM using TestNG framework throwing No SuchMethod Error any inputs on this?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, alm, leanft

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass baseBeforeClass(org.testng.TestRunner@74fe5c40)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.lft.report.ReportingProvider.getInstance()Lcom/hp/lft/report/ReportingProvider;
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.initReporter(UnitTestBase.java:314)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.TestNgUnitTestBase.classSetup(TestNgUnitTestBase.java:38)
    at unittesting.UnitTestClassBase.baseBeforeClass(UnitTestClassBase.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    <... internal TestNG methods ...>
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1411)


FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass baseAfterClass(org.testng.TestRunner@74fe5c40)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.lft.report.ReportingProvider.getInstance()Lcom/hp/lft/report/ReportingProvider;
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.closeReportLevels(UnitTestBase.java:176)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.TestNgUnitTestBase.classTearDown(TestNgUnitTestBase.java:77)
    at unittesting.UnitTestClassBase.baseAfterClass(UnitTestClassBase.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:212)
    <... internal TestNG methods ...>
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1411)
```

Comment: You have a CLASSPATH problem. You need to ensure that you have included the proper jars. Since you havent told us how you are managing your build path, its hard to say anything.

Comment: Yes, It is CLASSPATH problem and I am able to resolve it by adding the correct  jars to the CLASSPATH this problem will go away..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by placing the Correct jars to CLASSPATH and the main problem is the jars i was using are old jar as they dont have TestNG annotation method inside.

Solution : if this arises please check your jars are having these methods or not if not use the jar having those methods.